# Weird behaviour of jssor slider when deployed as cloud service on chrome

Tags: css, jssor, azure-cloud-services

I have a jssor slider on a website that is displaying full screen in debug mode on a large monitor but when I push it into the a cloud service for production deployment at ebill.budgetenergy.co.uk then there is white space being displayed to the right of the slider, any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: It seems white space appears only on ie 11. It caused by delay of window `resize` event firing, and it will look good after a while.

Comment: The issue is occurring on google chrome on 2100px screen, it is fine in IE, this is not a resizing issue, it is happening only when it is deployed as a cloud service in debug it fills the screen as expected

Comment: please leave an url of your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the above suggestion but it set the image to less than a half of the screen so I tried:

```
jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 2100));
```

2100px is the resolution of the largest monitor I have tried this on, the problem only seems to exhibit when it is deployed to azure and not in debug so maybe it is something being blocked on azure side

Answer (score 1):

Please replace

```
jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
```

with

```
jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(bodyWidth);
```

Comment: I have the line of code: jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 1920), 300)); in jssor.transition.js and also in my view page

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: please use `jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(parentWidth, 300));` then.

Comment: Also, please check css of the parent container to see if there is max-width which stop the parent container from expanding.

Comment: If I use jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(parentWidth, 300)); then the slider number tracker becomes blurry so I am happy with the fix that I have in place as it does not exhibit this problem